# onActivityResult() is not called after finish of SecondActivity

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I call SecondActivity on my FirstActivity. Please see below:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

on my SecondActivity, I finish its specific screen and setResult as RESULT_OK

```
    activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    activity.finish();
```

Back to my FirstActivity, I override the onActivityResult(params) method

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == 1) { //to make sure request was successful
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

But `onActivityResult()` wasn't called after SecondActivity is finished. Tried debugging and at first launch of FirstActivity, that's just the time that `onActivityResult()` is called but on return from the SecondActivity it isn't anymore.

What might be the problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you use this flag? `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);`

Comment: @HedeH, to always start my SecondActivity as a new task if it's not in background

Comment: And why do you need that?

Comment: @HedeH, read the docs. But it doesn't really solve my problem regarding the onActivityResulyt() not getting called. Thanks for pointing that out anyway

Comment: Did you set any `launchMode` on the `SecondActivity` tag in the `Manifest`?

Comment: No, didn't set any launchMode on the Manifest file

Comment: Any other interesting configuration in the `Manifest`? What does your `FirstActivity` extends? Why do you need to call `super.onActivityResult`? I'll gladly try to help but I feel some information is missing...

Answer (score 5):

You can't use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` and `startActivityForResult` together.

It's stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) of this flag:

> This flag can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the answere intent in your second Activity, it looks like this:

```
            Intent answIntent = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, answIntent); 

            finish();
```